# What does `float* const* ` mean?

Tags: c++, pointers

Take a look at this function signature:

```
AudioBlock (SampleType *const *channelData, size_t numberOfChannels, size_t startSampleIndex, size_t numberOfSamples)
```

from [here](https://docs.juce.com/master/classdsp_1_1AudioBlock.html#a3bcb01d97f828afad4db2f87ac10d827)

The main type used if `float*` so let's think of the signature as

```
AudioBlock (float *const *channelData, size_t numberOfChannels, size_t startSampleIndex, size_t numberOfSamples)
```

What does `float *const *channelData` mean? `channelData` should be a const pointer to a float pointer? What is a `const* something`? I don't see the type of the inner pointer.

Suppose I want to create a vector of zeros so I can pass to `AudioBlock`:

```
std::vector<float> v(bufferOriginal.getNumChannels()*bufferOriginal.getNumSamples(), 0);
```

How do I get a `float *const *channelData` to this vector data?

Answer (score 3):

> What does `float* const*`  mean?

`float` is a fundamental floating point type. `T*` is a pointer to `T`. `const` is a qualifier that applies to whatever is on the left side of it (except when it is the left most token in which case it applies to right). Since both qualifier and the pointer apply to left, it is easies to read from right to left (there are more complicated cases where this simplified rule of thumb is wrong):

```
float * const *  // original
* const * float  // reversed
          *          | const *          |           float // added spaces and separators
non-const pointer to | const pointer to | non-const float // translated to english
```

Arrays are an example of more complex cases where just right to left doesn't work. For the more complex rule that works with all compound types, see "clockwise rule" or "spiral rule".

> So it's not possible to get a float* const * to the vector data then, right?

You could, if you had a vector like this:

```
std::vector<float*> vector_of_pointers;
float* const* ptr = vector_of_pointers.data();
```

You could make element of that vector point to your vector of floats.

```
vector_of_pointers.push_back(v.data());
```

Comment: So it's not possible to get a `float* const *` to the vector data then, right?

Answer (score 0):

This parameter declaration

```
float *const *channelData
```

means that the variable `channelData` (read from tight to left) is a pointer to a constant pointer (the pointer itself that is constant) to a non-constant object of the type float.

To make it more clear consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    float x = 1.1f;
    float y = 2.2f;
    
    printf( "x = %f\n", x );

    float * const px = &x;
    
//  px = &y;    //  error: assignment of read-only variable ‘px’
    *px = y;
    
    printf( "x = %f\n", x );
    
    float * const * ppx = &px;
    
//  *ppx = &y;  //  error: assignment of read-only location ‘*ppx’

    **ppx = 3.0f;
    
    printf( "x = %f\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
x = 1.100000
x = 2.200000
x = 3.000000
```

As you can see as the pointer `px` is a constant variable it has to be initialized when it is declared. You can not change it such a way that it will point to another variable. But you can use `pc` to change the value of the object pointed to by `px`. The variable `ppx` is a pointer to such a pointer.

Comment: I think I understand, but why a buffer would have a double pointer as a constructor? Shouldn't it be just a pointer to the other buffer to copy from?

Comment: @Rafaelo It is another question. I did not see the provided reference.. All relevant code you should type directly in your question.